# Angular js Two way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are some values in the dropdown in my angular application. My requirement is, when user select any particular value from the dropdown, he'll get the complete array corresponding to that value.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-$filter-production</title>

    <script src="//ajax.goo gleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0- rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function (angular) {
            'use strict';
            angular.module('filterExample', [])
            .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
                $scope.originalText = [
                    { name: "Object1", shape: "circle", color: "red" },
                    { name: "Object2", shape: "square", color: "orange" },
                    { name: "Object3", shape: "triangle", color: "yellow" },
                    { name: "Object4", shape: "circle", color: "green" },
                    { name: "Object5", shape: "sphere", color: "blue" },
                    { name: "Object6", shape: "hexagon", color: "indigo" },
                    { name: "Object7", shape: "square", color: "violet" },
                    { name: "Object8", shape: "triangle", color: "red" }
                ]

                //$scope.xxx = {d:'Object1'};
                $scope.xxx = { d: null };
                $scope.filteredText = $filter('filter')($scope.originalText, { name: $scope.xxx.d });
            });
        })(window.angular);
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="filterExample">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h3>{{ originalText }}</h3>
        <h3>{{ filteredText }}</h3>

        <select ng-model="xxx.d" ui-select2="">
            <option ng-repeat="item in originalText" value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</option>"
        </select>

        {{xxx.d}}

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Code in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UWJ4oC71D8BRhbe8qwuL?p=preview)

**Here I want that, when user selects any particular value in dropdown, then he should get the filtered array.**

Comment: do you wanted to use `ui-select2` there

Comment: What should user get in the filtered arrray when user select any value from the dropdown? Should it be the object of selected value?

Comment: Like if user selects **Object2** , then he wil get this array : '{ name: "Object2", shape: "square", color: "orange" }'

Comment: No pankaj, No special requirement here for **ui-select**, i was just checking the use of ui-select.

Comment: @HardikMunjaal what do you mean by filter array..here is  plunkr with dropdown which is selecting value http://plnkr.co/edit/J5kUB3EnonCnuodRpyBx?p=preview

Comment: @pankajparkar    In my application there is :- `<h3>{{ originalText }}</h3>` which show complete array of items.I want this , suppose you selected **Circle** from the dropdown , then i want to print only these array `"name":"Object1","shape":"circle","color":"red"` ,`{"name":"Object4","shape":"circle","color":"green"}`  having shape =circle.

Comment: @HardikMunjaal cool I'll do that soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use filter for achieving this thing

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h3>{{ originalText }}</h3>
  <h3>{{ filteredText =(originalText| filter: {shape: xxx.shape}) }}</h3>
  <select ng-model="xxx" ng-options="item as item.shape for item in originalText">
  </select>
</div>
```

**Update**

You can do this filtering from controller by calling filtering method on change using `ng-change` directive

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="xxx" ng-options="item as item.shape for item in originalText" ng-change="changeFunction()">
</select>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.changeFunction = function(){
  $scope.filteredText = $filter('filter')($scope.originalText, { shape: $scope.xxx.shape}, true);
}
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/J5kUB3EnonCnuodRpyBx?p=preview)

Comment: Bro, I want the same result but in different way.   **i want to use these filters in javascript not in view**

Comment: **like i was using** `$scope.filteredText = $filter('filter')($scope.originalText, { name: $scope.xxx.d});`  But the problem here is that **$scope.xxx.d** is not dynamically changing value. :(